# Rails 4 - Has_many, Using Nested Form to Edit a Specfic Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms

I have a User who has many Accounts through a User_Accounts model. The User_Accounts model also tracks other information such as admin and billing access. Via the user edit form, I want to be able to edit the admin and billing boolean fields for the users current account.

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :owned_account, class_name: 'Account', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  has_many :user_accounts
  has_many :accounts, through: :user_accounts

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_accounts

end
```

user_account.rb
class UserAccount < ActiveRecord::Base

```
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In the users controller, I specified which user_account I wanted to edit via the nested form and assigned to the @user_account instance variable.

users_controller.rb

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_account = @user.user_accounts.find_by_account_id(current_account)
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: "edit" 
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, user_accounts_attributes: [:admin, :billing] )
    end
```

user/edit.html.erb

```
    <%= f.fields_for :user_accounts, @user_account do |o| %>
        <%= o.check_box :admin, class: 'checkbox' %>
    <% end %>
```

When I submit the change, it successfully saves the user record, but doesn't update the User_account record. It appears to be passing the following:

```
{"name"=>"Colin 21", "email"=>"mike21@example.com", "user_accounts_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"admin"=>"1"}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id is required to edit an object via accepts_nested_attributes_for. Seems that the id attribute is not allowed through strong parameters.

Try changing the user_params method in 'users_controller.rb'

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, user_accounts_attributes: [:id, :admin, :billing] )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a hidden field for `user account`'s `id` field within `fields_for` part of the form too.